# Rebol 2 Stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Rebol 2 stopped working on Ubuntu after upgrading to 15.10.
I am getting error-

```
./rebol
./rebol: error while loading shared libraries: libXaw.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried to install libXaw-

```
sudo apt-get install libXaw:i686
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXaw
```

Fresh install from deb package by Massimiliano gives unresolved dependency error.

Any suggestions to get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get it working for you

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
apt-get install libx11-6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxaw7:i386 libfreetype6:i386
apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
```

Thanks to @earl https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17707389#17707389

Comment: Thanks. That got it working.         However, Ubuntu server was not giving libxaw7:i386 manually. I was getting network connection error. Had to change server from India to Main. Then click on 'Install' couple of times in Ubuntu Software Centre to get it finally.